# Prevent pressing back button from showing ProgressDialog android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an AsyncTask subclass in my main activity in which I have overridden the onPreExecute to show a ProgressDialog while the thread is executing, and also overridden the onPostExecute method to publish the results of executing the thread in a separate activity as such:

```
   // progress dialog to show user that the scheduling request is being processed
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Intent scheduleTasksIntent = TaskSchedulingActivity.newIntent(getActivity(),
                (ArrayList<Task>) frontTasks, (ArrayList<Task>) preferableTasks);
        startActivity(scheduleTasksIntent);
    }
```

When I press the back button from the second activity (the TaskSchedulingActivity) to go back to the main activity where the AsyncTask subclass was created, the main activity appears but the progress dialog also shows and only stops when I click somewhere else on the screen.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the result when the back button is pressed.]

I was wondering how I could stop this so clicking back simply returns to my main activity and does not show the progress dialog?

Comment: just don't call show on progressBar or call dismiss when you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. In your onPostExecute, do `this.dialog.dismiss()` before going to the next activity.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.